Maintaining Consistent Visual Border-Radius for Buttons of Different Sizes Using CSS calc()
I’m currently working on a project that involves two buttons of different sizes. Both buttons are designed with the same border-radius of 6px. However, when rendered in the browser, they appear to have different border-radius values. The smaller button seems to have a larger border-radius compared to the larger button, despite both being set to the same pixel value.
My goal is to make the smaller button appear as a scaled-down version of the larger button, maintaining the same visual border-radius. This means that both buttons should look identical in terms of their border-radius, regardless of their size.
Is there a way to achieve this using CSS calc()? I’m asking for a solution involving calc() because I’m not allowed to modify the 6px value as it’s going to be used as a variable in my project.


.small {
    padding: 0.1rem 0.6rem;
    font-size: 0.475rem;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
}

.large {
    padding: .5rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
}
<button class="small">Test</button>
<button class="large">Test</button>





.small {
    padding: 0.1rem 0.6rem;
    font-size: 0.475rem;
    color: white;
    border-radius: calc(6px / 2); // This is how I tried to solve it
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
}

.large {
    padding: .5rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
}
<button class="small">Test</button>
<button class="large">Test</button>




The buttons do have the same border-radius. I don't think that is the problem, what you are seeing is an optical illusion because the buttons are different heights.. When you overlap them it is obvious they have the same radius. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oNRyvyq

A visually consistent border-radius between buttons of different sizes, you can indeed use CSS's calc() function to adjust the border-radius proportionally to the size of the buttons.
The smaller button will have a border-radius that appears scaled down appropriately.


:root {
    --base-border-radius: 6px;
    --base-font-size: 1rem; /* This should match the font-size of the larger button */
}

.small {
    padding: 0.1rem 0.6rem;
    font-size: 0.475rem;
    color: white;
    border-radius: calc(var(--base-border-radius) * (0.475 / 1)); /* Adjusted based on the font-size ratio */
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
}

.large {
    padding: .5rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: white;
    border-radius: var(--base-border-radius);
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
}
<button class="small">Test</button>
<button class="large">Test</button>



